# using rails.vim Rake run spec in MacVim, how to get colored output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rspec, macvim

when using Rake to run a spec, the output in quickfix is not colored, meaning, it doesn't have green for passing specs and red for failing specs. Is this something solvable? Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Tim Pope, the author of rails.vim, not much that can be done about that; Vim doesn't support ANSI color codes.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible by recompiling vim as this plugin suggest. I haven't tried it myself.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302