# Enable colored output in mvim

Tags: vim, rspec, macvim

I'm running rspec from within mvim with `:!rspec spec/lib`, however if I include --color flag, I get

```
[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m

Finished in 0.01708 seconds
[32m7 examples, 0 failures[
```

I tried `--tty` flag which works with rstakeout, but no help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using rails.vim Rake run spec in MacVim, how to get colored output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441156/using-rails-vim-rake-run-spec-in-macvim-how-to-get-colored-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

MacVim does it's own graphics rendering, which is not implemented as/via a terminal emulator, so it has no concept of ANSI color codes etc. I believe I remember the author of MacVim commenting that this will never be supported, which is a shame.

When I was using MacVim, I'd run `rspec --no-color` to at least avoid the escape sequences cluttering the output.

I've since switched to vim (running inside tmux in full-screen iTerm2) and it's nice to get back the color output of console commands.

Comment: sadly i've been running with `rspec --no-color` as well.